# When I use the PutObjectCommand is there an option to set an expiration of the object?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When I use the PutObjectCommand is there an option to expire the object after a specific timeout?

For example, when I use the getSignedUrl there is an option to expire the url after a specific timeout.

I want the same thing but to delete or mark the object for deletion.

Comment: No, but you can use a [lifecycle policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html) for groups of objects.

Comment: @jarmod Thanks I saw that but it looks like it occurs after a minimum of one day. I attempted to specify a fraction value at .04 (one hour) and it wouldn't accept it.

Comment: You'd have to implement something that fine-grained yourself. You could do it with a combination of S3 events (trigger Lambda, write object key & expiration timestamp to DynamoDB) and EventBridge Schedules (to trigger a Lambda each N minutes to query the DDB table and expire objects).

Comment: @jarmod I saw some examples here. I'll look into that if there aren't any expire like parameters. I couldn't find any documentation on the parameters.